# Cannot see "Course Connection" option in Process Builder

Tags: process-builder

I using Salesforce's HEDA fields. I am trying to send Survey Invitation whenever a new "Course Connection" is created using process builder. I am not getting the option "Course Connection" while creating action and giving the Recipient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you a system admin? Keep in mind the api name of the object is 'hed__Course_Enrollment__c".